# How do I stop new connects?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am trying to search a Server and once the client finds it, he stops searching for new Servers. But now the Client finds the Server, can get messages from the Server but trys connecting to other once so I cant write the Server.

Can u guys tell me what I need to do with my Code?

ty Bono

```
for (pcip = 0; pcip <= 253; pcip++) {
            clientVerbindung = new ChatSocket(client.getUserName(), /*
                                                                     * Die IP an
                                                                     * welche
                                                                     * der
                                                                     * Client
                                                                     * verbindet
                                                                     */
            "10.4.0." + pcip, /* Der Port welcher verwendet wird */3005, client);
            clientVerbindung.start();
        }
```

ChatSocket:

```
public class ChatSocket extends Thread {

    private String nameDesUsers;
    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private P2P client;
    private String user;
    private String path;

    private DataInputStream inStream;
    private DataOutputStream outStream;

    public ChatSocket(String nameDesUsers, String ip, int port, P2P client) {
        this.nameDesUsers = nameDesUsers;
        this.port = port;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);

            InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

            inStream = new DataInputStream(in);
            outStream = new DataOutputStream(out);

            // Intepretiert den erhaltenen Text. Passiert nur bei diesem Socket
            // und nicht umbedingt auch beim sender
            outStream.writeUTF(nameDesUsers);
            while (true) {
                String utf = inStream.readUTF();

                client.setMessage("Server", utf);
            }

            // Mögliche Fehlermeldungen
        } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
            System.out.println("Client Fehler: " + uhe.toString());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Client Fehler: " + ioe.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Die Verbindung wurde geschlossen.");
    }

    public void sendText(String message) {
        try {
            if (message != null) {
                // Nimmt den aktuellen Text aus dem clientText und schickt ihn
                // an den Server
                outStream.writeUTF(message);
            }

            // Mögliche Fehlermeldungen
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Fehler beim senden im Client: "
                    + ioe.toString());
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            System.out.println("Fehler beim senden im Client: "
                    + npe.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if there is a valid connection, if so: break from for loop.

Comment: @Max how do you check for the vaild connection? isalive?

Comment: Could you show me the ChatSocket contents?

Comment: You should show the ChatSocket contents as that is where the connecting and important processes take place.

Comment: @Max okay added it now

Comment: @JavaFanatic Was this that file u were thinking of?

Comment: While it can be done this way, with careful programming, I think the UDP broadcasting technique is a better tool for the job. See [here](http://michieldemey.be/blog/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast/) for example.

Comment: @vanOekel It can be done this way? do you mean checking with for a valid connection?

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a valid connection you will get a `ConnectException.`

*Ergo,* if you don't get that exception, you have a valid connection.

Hard to see what the mystery is.

Comment: well yes that is what I can read on the consol but how do I make it stop trying to connect with other Servers?